# rasbian owncloud problem Package php7.0-curl is not available

Tags: raspbian, owncloud

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt install -y apache2 mariadb-server libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0-gd php7.0-json php7.0-mysql php7.0-curl php7.0-intl php7.0-mcrypt php-imagick php7.0-zip php7.0-xml php7.0-mbstring
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package php7.0-curl is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

Comment: Don’t try to install obsolete packages. If you just install apache and mysql they should install most dependencies automatically

Comment: PHP 7.0 is not available in Buster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With:

```
@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt install -y apache2 mariadb-server libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0-gd php7.0-json php7.0-mysql php7.0-curl php7.0-intl php7.0-mcrypt php-imagick php7.0-zip php7.0-xml php7.0-mbstring
```

you try to install `php7.0-curl` together with other packages. If it is not available so just don't install it with:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt install -y apache2 mariadb-server libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0-gd php7.0-json php7.0-mysql php7.0-intl php7.0-mcrypt php-imagick php7.0-zip php7.0-xml php7.0-mbstring
```

or use one of the available packages:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ apt list php*curl
Listing... Done
php-curl/stable 2:7.3+69 all
php7.1-curl/stable 7.1.20-1+b2 armhf
php7.2-curl/stable 7.2.9-1+b2 armhf
php7.3-curl/stable 7.3.4-2 armhf
```

Comment: tnks ,I tried the "php7.1" and it worked